# Embedding a swf on a wordpress page

Tags: javascript, xml, wordpress, flash

I'm trying to embed a .swf into a wordpress page. This sounds simple, but it isn't working and I cannot fathom out why. I've uploaded all the relevant files onto the server, and I'm fairly sure all the filepaths are correct. The folder containing the .fla and .swf files also contained an index.html file, which I have put into a template. I've tried putting the supplied code into the HTML on the page, I've tried simply using said template, and the best I'm getting is a blank area which doesn't load the flash content.

Could anyone suggest what I might have done wrong? Unfortunately I can't paste the code into here as it's full of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should us swfObject Plugin : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-swfobject/

Answer (score 0):

There are actually so many ways to do that. However one of the easist way (not safest way tho, just my opinion) is using html table and use embedded code.

Remember, I would like to mention again that this is not the safest way!!! But , yes its easy!

First of all, just go to [this](http://www.freevideocoding.com/) site (you can use any other site which also creates you an embedded code as well)  and then just follow the screen shots,

First

[image]

second

[image]

third

[image]

fourth

[image]

fifth

[image]

sixth is the last one

[image]

I hope this will help.