# How do I embed a .swf object on my wordpress.org site?

Tags: flash, wordpress

Embarrassingly simple I know, but I'm not a programmer and it's amazing how mixed the information is on this.. Nothing's working for me.

I generated a flash object using pc software, and now I'm trying to get that on my site. I managed to go as far as uploading the object htm (+ all corresponding files) to my ftp. 
Now I just want to get that on to my index page and whatever I try is creating a blank flash object.

Here's the .htm tester http://top5bali.com/flash/TOP%205%20BALI.htm

One thing confusing me is that the .swf file located here ../flash/engine/cu3ox.swf is showing up as a blank flash object, while in the .htm it's working.

I want to insert this object into the header section of the main page top5bali.com

Any help is much appreciated!

Regards,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

I've spent many hours working with this sort of bug. Mostly, the problem is that urls are reset to the base url in wordpress, so loading some of the resources needed to run flash can be problematic. Since often they rely on relative urls.

First of all, make sure to load the js files needed with enqueue script. IF the file is self contained you should be able to load it from any directory.

However, if your swf file is dependent on an external xml file then I've only had success loading it from the home directory. If this is the case you may want to create a blank html file with the swf loaded in it, then use an iframe to load it onto the page you want. 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/iframe-embedder/
This plugin does work with 3.0.1.

Good luck, and feel free to post questions.

Comment: Hi Jack -it's odd how tricky this can be. I'll use the iframe as a workaround anyway, thanks for that.

Comment: Pleasure! For the most part, i LOVE wordpress. But there still are kinks to work out... Good Luck!

Comment: actually there is a pretty easy way ( embedded swf) but I'm not saying its the best way or safe, but its very easy. you can check it out if you are interested . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204265/embedding-a-swf-on-a-wordpress-page/19646194#19646194