# Embedding an SWF Video in Wordpress: Many roads to failure

Tags: html, wordpress, object, embed, swfobject

I've been racking my brain and my search bar with what I thought was a simple question:

I'm trying to add an SWF file, hosted on the same server as the blog, into a blog post. I need it to autoplay and have controls. I'm also trying to avoid using the embed element, i've read it's wonky.

When using SWFobject Wordpress mangles the conditional comments, deletes parts of the code, adds the embed element, and sometimes changes the dimensions.

I've also tried using Wordpress Shortcode: it does nothing but hyperlink to the video. I'm thinking this is due to no oEmbed support though i'm not sure.

Is there a way to turn off Wordpress's Object/comment mangling? What is best practice for using Wordpress and embedding video?

Comment: actually there is a pretty easy way ( embedded swf) but you have mentioned that its wonky :) I'm not saying its the best way or safe, but its very easy. you can check it out if you are interested . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204265/embedding-a-swf-on-a-wordpress-page/19646194#19646194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone out there is running into similiar issues:

I used JW Player free, which uses the `script` element in the post body to generate the swf code, bypassing wordpress's mangle tangle.